# assign javascript variable to django template variable

Tags: python, django

Is there is any way to assign `javascript` variable to `django template variable` ?

In short can i do like this  ?

```
<script>

    var x=10;

    {{somedvar}}=x;

</script>
```

Comment: Can you please how you solved this, im in the same situation.

Comment: @Kevin can you please brief me about the situation you are facing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is executed in your visitors' browsers after Django has already finished responding to the request. So no, it is not possible, and it actually doesn't make sense. Besides plain Django does not support assignment to variables within templates *at all*, so it is a bit far-fetched to expect that it would support it in this very specific case.